# How do I isolate a .json file?

Tags: python, alpha-vantage

I was trying to split some parts of a .json, to completely isolate parts of a .json file from an API I found.

This is trying to isolate the open share price of any stocks on the internet. I've consulted with Stack Overflow, but I think I may have made a mistake in my paraphrasing.

```
# example
import sys
import requests
import json
from ticker import *


def main():
    stock_ticker = input("Name the stock ticker?\n")
    time2 = int(input("How many minutes do you want to view history?\n"))

    #separate file to generate URL for API
    url =  webpage(stock_ticker, time2)
    response = requests.get(url)

    assert response.status_code == 200

    data = json.loads(response.text)
    open_share_price = data["Time Series (5min)"]["2019-11-01 16:00:00"]["1. open"]
    print(open_share_price)
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Returns

```
136.800
```

I've been wanting to get open share prices from different time frames, not just 16 :00:00, and not just at 5 min intervals.

I'm not great at programming, so any help would be gratefully received. Sorry in advance for my conciseness errors

Edit: The link for the data. Sorry I didn't include it the first time around. https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=kmb&interval=5min&apikey=exampleapikey

Comment: Why is there a // for a comment in Python?

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake.

Comment: if you have to work in more than one element then you usually have to use `for`-loop for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to more than one element then you should use `for`-loop

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=kmb&interval=5min&apikey=exampleapikey'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

for key, val in data["Time Series (5min)"].items():
    print(key, val["1. open"])
```

If you want to keep it as JSON then create new directory to keep values and later save it in file.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=kmb&interval=5min&apikey=exampleapikey'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

new_data = dict()

for key, val in data["Time Series (5min)"].items():
    new_data[key] = val["1. open"]

#print(new_data)    

with open('new_data.json', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(json.dumps(new_data))
```